# Switching a project written in Lua to a compiled language

Tags: c#, c++, java, lua

I am experimenting with game development in Lua using the Love2D framework, and while it works fine, I am getting tired of using a dynamic scripting language. I would like to have better performance, misspellings caught at compile time, and the ability to create efficient data structures for things like 2D vectors.

I thought about some alternatives:

C++ should be very efficient, but it also would make me have to worry about low-level details like manual memory management, and compiling for different platforms.

Java is cross-platform, but as far as I know it does not support pass-by-value data structures, which I would really like. There are also the claims of it being large and slow, but I'm not sure how valid they are.

C# seems to have similar advantages and disadvantages to Java, plus it only officially supports Windows, which makes me hesitant since I mainly use Linux and would like my program to be cross-platform.

So, if my ideas about one of those languages is wrong, or you have other suggestions, I would be interested to find out.

Comment: Why do you think Lua is slow? Since [0.8.0](http://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8750#p53963), Love2D uses [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/), which just-in-time compiles Lua to [extremely efficient](http://luajit.org/performance.html) code.

Answer (score 2):

> C++ should be very efficient, but it also would make me have to worry about low-level details like manual memory management, and compiling for different platforms.

Modern C++ highly discourages manual memory management. You should instead use smart pointers like `unique_ptr` and allocation functions like `make_unique` and never manually allocate or deallocate memory, aside from the implementation of certain very low-level routines (which you don't often need to do). You do need to think about memory management a bit harder than you do in Lua in terms of proper lifetime management, but that's a good thing IMO.

> C# seems to have similar advantages and disadvantages to Java, plus it only officially supports Windows, which makes me hesitant since I mainly use Linux and would like my program to be cross-platform.

Microsoft *officially* recommends Mono for non-Windows platforms. Mono is quite capable, up-to-date, and complete. It even has various features and advantages that Microsoft's C# does not. Unity is a well-known very popular game engine that makes heavy use of Mono and runs on Windows, Linux, OS X, iOS, Android, Flash, and even HTML5 (without plugins).

C# does *not* have the same disadvantages as Java. It supports value type semantics (though it's statically part of the type based on whether it's declared as a `class` or a `struct`), supports "real" generics, and via Mono even supports native SIMD usage.

C# is probably the best choice for you. There's even things like [NLua](http://nlua.org/) which would help you gradually or partially port your code.

Comment: It's nice to know that I wouldn't be stuck with a lower-quality implementation of C# on Linux, and that it has less limitations. I'll look at it more seriously, then.

Answer (score 1):

About c++: You dont really need to worry about memory management. Ofc you handle memory yourself, but its not as hard as in C. In C++ you just allocate your memory by creating a Object (new xyz();) and free this memory by deleting it (delete var;). No more manual malloc() and stuff)

About Java: Java supports Call-by-value with primitives and Call-by-reference with Objects. WHY do you need call-by-value with objects? This is just not needed and slow as shit. if you REALLY want to copy the instance to pass it in you just can copy the Instance yourself befor calling the method. And Java isnt that slow. It was slow in earlier versions but now its almost as fast as C++, sometimes even faster. But ofc, if you really optimize the shit out of c++, then c++ will beat java. but overall, java is fast.

Comment: The reason I want call-by-value is so that I can work with 2D vectors as single objects that support all the usual math operators, instead of two floating point number variables. While that's doable with call-by-reference, I would assume that causing each math operator in an expression to allocate memory is extremely slow compared to passing structures with just 2 fields by value.